# Angular SPA for only authenticated portions of the site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am thinking of adding AngularJS to a project I'm working on.

To avoid dealing with SEO issues I think I just want the single page app experience for authenticated users on pages where SEO is not an issue.

Can I have my rails routes and angular routes working essentially side by side?

Comment: That's the main idea, yes. You have a "base" route where you client app resides and Angular routes (which will be relative to that "base" route). In that sense, you could have one different Angular app for each 'get' route you have in your rails app... :)

Comment: OK, so just so I'm clear. My index, about, help, etc could be plain erb filed served by rails and all of my user profile, etc. pages could be angular? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Basically yes. You could either have a route under which you will load angular (for instance your.route.path/users#), or you could just have it in your assets folder and have angular run under your.route.path/#